# What is the most reliable way of implementing toFixed()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement toFixed() to round to decimal places in a reliable way (the current toFixed() function returns different results across different browsers).

My idea is implement it with `Number.prototype.toFixed = function(c){};`

I have tried many options and only one seems to work fine but I'm not confident about it:

By multiplying/dividing by 10 several times and rounding (`(0.069).toFixed(2);` returns "0.06999999999999999"):

```js
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(c){
    var c =  isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 0 : c;
    var n = this;
    for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
        n *= 10;
    }
    n = Math.round(n);
    for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
        n /= 10;
    }
    n = (n+"").split(".");
    if(c==0){
        return n[0];
    }
    if(n[1] == void 0){
        n[1] = "";
    }
    while(n[1].length<c){
        n[1]+="0";
    }
    return n[0]+"."+n[1];
};
```

By managing the number as a String (I still have bugs with this one, for example: `(0.0999).toFixed(2)` gives me "1.10")

```js
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(c){
    var c =  isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 0 : c;
        var d = (this+"").split(".");
        if(d[1] == void 0){
            d[1] = "";
        }
        if(d[1].length>c){
            if(parseInt(d[1].charAt(c))>=5){
                var cont = 0;
                while(cont<c-1&&d[1].charAt(cont)==='0'){
                    cont++;
                }
                var temp="";
                while(cont--){
                    temp += "0";
                }
                d[1]=temp+(parseInt(d[1].substring(0,c))+1)+"";
                if(d[1].length>c){
                    d[0]=(parseInt(d[0])+1)+"";
                    d[1]=d[1].substring(1);
                }
            } else {
                d[1] = d[1].substring(0,c);
            }
        }
        if(c==0){
            return d[0];
        }
        while(d[1].length<c){
            d[1]+="0";
        }
        return d[0]+"."+d[1];
};
```

By multiplying/dividing by 10^c and rounding I haven't seen any problem but I'm not too confident:

```js
Number.prototype.toFixed = function(c){
    var c =  isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 0 : c;
    var n = this;
    var z = "1";
    for(var i=0; i<c; i++){
        z+="0";
    }
    n = Math.round(n*z);
    n /= z;
    n = (n+"").split(".");
    if(c==0){
        return n[0];
    }
    if(n[1] == void 0){
        n[1] = "";
    }
    while(n[1].length<c){
        n[1]+="0";
    }
    return n[0]+"."+n[1];
};
```

My best bet would be the string manipulation one because you don't mess with the uncertainties of floats, though it's getting harder to debug than I thought and I'm starting to believe I'll never have it perfect. Does someone else have one already implemented besides these?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use:

```
function RoundNumber(input, numberDecimals)
{
  numberDecimals = +numberDecimals || 0; // +var magic!

  var multiplyer = Math.pow(10.0, numberDecimals);

  return Math.round(input * multiplyer) / multiplyer;
}
```

Examples:

```
console.log( RoundNumber(1234.6789, 0) ); // prints 1234
console.log( RoundNumber(1234.6789, 1) ); // prints 1234.6
console.log( RoundNumber(1234.6789, 2) ); // prints 1234.67
console.log( RoundNumber(1234.6789, -1) ); // prints 1230
```

I've used it in Chrome and Firefox.